# What happened to my underset?

Tags: katex

```
\hat{y} = \hat{f}(x) = \overset{C}{argmax}\underset{c=1}\> p(y = c|x, D)
```

produces this:

[image]

How can I use `\underset` to get `c=1` under `argmax`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest not using `\underset` and `\overset` but instead declaring `argmax` as an operator. In that way, `argmax` is also typeset correctly.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{argmax}

\begin{document}
\[
\hat{y} = \hat{f}(x) = \argmax_{c=1}^{C}\> p(y = c|x, D)
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: @kb9alpp This is *the* correct answer. In KaTeX and LaTeX you can do `\operatorname*{argmax}_{c=1}^C` that will do the right thing as well. Unfortunately KaTeX doesn't know `\DeclareMathOperator`. Anyway, KaTeX specific questions are off-topic on the site.

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks! The one line ```\hat{y} = \hat{f}(x) = \argmax_{c=1}^{C}\> p(y = c|x, D)``` works.

Comment: I didn't realize the katex tag, sorry. I can't provide a suitable answer for KaTeX. If anyone else can, feel free :)

Answer (score 0):

Just put the `\underset` part inside the argument of the `\overset`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
\hat{y} = \hat{f}(x) = \overset{C}{\underset{c=1}{argmax}}\> p(y = c|x, D)
\]

\end{document}
```

Edit: also, argmax isn't typeset correctly, it's an operator and shouldn't be rendered with slanted letters.